# Выполнить PHP скрипт паралельно

Tags: php

Нужно при обращении пользователя к скрипту например index.php, внутри него выполнить функцию или скрипт паралельно, конкретно нужно обратися к API получить большой JSON и записать его в БД. Как вывести данные index.php не дожидаясь результатов обработки JSON.

Пробовал `fsockopen()`, но как то медленно получается, особенно если нужно паралелить два и более действия... Возможно существуют, какие то другие не сложные решения этой задачи на PHP.

Comment: ==Пробовал fsockopen(), но как то медленно получается==  Должно получаться быстро. Что-то Вы не так делали

Comment: Очередь реализовать.

Comment: Можно использовать что-то вроде Gearman для запуска задач в очередях (как уже подсказали выше). У него есть поддержка запуска задач в фоне.

Comment: @Confireus, Возможно Вы правы... Медленность заключается в том что fsockopen, задействует сервер, и тратится время на установку соединения. Если выполнить три fsockopen, у меня на локальной машине получается около 1500ms...

Comment: пользователю для работы нужны эти сведения? если нет, то пишите в базу, что и для кого надо сделать, а потом кроном ходите и периодически выполняете эти задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете PHP-fpm, то функция `fastcgi_finish_request()` позволяет отправить Web серверу ответ без остановки самого PHP скрипта

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но данный вариант не работает под Windows. Да в дальнейшем сервер будет на UNIX, но в данный момент разработка идет на Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отправить несколько запросов одновременно, попробуйте [curl_multi_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), это позволит отправить ваши запросы параллельно, но все равно быстрее чем время самого долгого запроса у вас не получится.

P.S. В идеале эту задачу стоит решать по другому:

1. Пришел запрос, записали в БД его, отдали клиенту ответ "ждите, вот ваш ID"
2. Клиент спрашивает, вот мой ID, что там ? вы ему отвечаете "ждите, ваш запрос обрабатывается"
3. Обрабатываете запрос (крон, демон)
4. При очередном запросе клиента "вот мой ID, что там ?" - возвращаете результат